# Konica Minolta C250 - user authentication

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, print-drivers

I am not able to install drivers for konica minolta c250 on windows 7 64bit. Windows XP is ok, but on Win7 i cant fill the User Authentication window (it is disabled as you can see on attached picture)... Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Same issue here for bizhub 420

Answer (score 0):

It's not turned on. Go to the printer properties in the control panel, and click the second last tab with the additional add-ons (I.e. finisher unit, etc). User authentication and account track are not settings retrieved automatically